# Return an empty data set with Status Code 200 instead of 404 Not Found error when no data is present

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using ASP.NET core, I need to change instances of NotFound(), which is being used when no data is returned to the front end and giving the users a 404 error. I need to refactor this so that it will instead return an empty data set with Status Code 200.

Here is what I currently have that needs changed:

```
       if (obj != null)
                    return Ok(obj);
                else
                    return NotFound();
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that your backend is doing the right thing, It is indicating that the **obj** is not found. The frontend should take care of this, otherwise the next thing that they will ask you for is to change the error response from 500 to 200 and that isn't good. However if you insist then you can try this:

```
    if (obj != null)
                return Ok(obj);
            else
                return Ok(new {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of the following will solve your question;

```
return Page();
```

or

```
return View();
```